# Gather rows results from query into one row with google sheet

Tags: sql, google-sheets, join, google-query-language

I am filtering a weekly timetable regarding a certain day. The results are displayed on two rows as follow : hours and corresponding content.
I'd like to merge each result into single cells as : hours + corresponding content.
I unsuccesfully tried with the functions join, concat, concatenate.
In addition, I'd like to have an arrayformula in order not to repeat the function in other rows.

[image]

Here is my sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uJDeie3FZeZ31BMIbZhnImvQlIn9CQ3CHohI34P29RA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!A3:"&B2&"20"); 
 "select A,"&B2&" where "&B2&"<>''")&CHAR(10));;9^9)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, the second formula is perfectly working (but not the first one with TRIM) : =ARRAYFORMULA(SUPPRESPACE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!A3:"&B2&"20");  "select A,"&B2&" where "&B2&"<>''")&CAR(10));;9^9)))